# Await and then usage issues when switching states

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

By default The text to speech engine uses an async call, this causes the main Dart thread to go on with whatever line of code comes next, this leads up to another setstate() call after the TTS speak function which reverts the animation state from Speaking to Idle almost instantly.

is there any way to avoid this issue?

I want it to work as follows:

```
setstate(() => _animation = 'Speaking')
```

wait until the TTS is finished speaking

```
setstate(() => _animation = 'Idle')
```

If I'm misunderstanding something, could you please point it out? in case this is how Dart works then if you have any workarounds that'd be great.

Simplified code for inspection:

```
  void _speak(String sentence) async {
    updateRiveRoot(_animation = 'Speak');
    setState(() => _isSpeaking = true);

    if (!_isSpeaking) {
      await tts.awaitSpeakCompletion(true);
      tts.speak(sentence).then((result) {
        if (result != null) {
          print("getting here");// not being preinted out
          setState(() => _isListening = false);
          setState(() => _isSpeaking = false);
          updateRiveRoot(_animation = 'Idle');
        }
      });
    } else {
      setState(() => _isSpeaking = true);
    }
    print("isSpeaking is $_isSpeaking and animation is $_animation");
  }
```

I have scrolled through the TTS documentation but couldn't find useful information on the problem I'm currently facing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TTS, but most asynchronous calls return a `Future` that you can wait for.  If you're not already familiar with `Future`s, see: [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017280/).  If that's not helpful, please show an example of the async call.

Comment: @jamesdlin I have added a short version of what I want to do.  as you can see I have the await in front of the future call, but it is being handled asynchronously then moving on on the main thread skipping the speaking animation altogether :< If you got any pointers on where I should be looking that also would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using this plugin?  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, any suggestions? sorry for the cross-posting btw but I gotta submit this to my professor very soon :'<

Comment: I suggest you follow the example provided here:  https://medium.com/flutterdevs/flutter-text-to-speech-3ed66ebec523

Comment: There's also a Dart-specific example here: https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: In short, you need to set up at least three event handlers.  I don't see you doing this in your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

try to use .then,

```
void _speak(String sentence) async {
    if (!_isSpeaking) {
      setState(() => _animation = 'Speak');
      setState(() => _isSpeaking = true);

      tts.speak(sentence).then((result) {
        if (result != null) {
          _isListening = false;
          _isSpeaking = false;
          setState((){});
        }
      });


}

 } else {
      setState(() => _isSpeaking = false);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but unfortunately the then() part didn't execute for some reason.